# Is it useful list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension, pyserial

```
import serial as ser
import serial.tools.list_ports as listport
import re

try:
    # VID regex
    regex_vplogVID = re.compile(r'{\S+}_VID')

    # I want to find COM port by using specific hwid
    port_device = [n.device for n in listport.comports() if re.findall(regex_vplogVID, n.hwid)]

    vplogserial = ser.Serial(port_device[0])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Actually, I'm newbie programmer using python.
I want to find port using unique hwid but I think list comprehension is not proper because port will be returned just one.

Am I using simply for-loop code? 
Please share your comments. :) Thank you for your reading.

Comment: If there's indeed only one match, don't use a list comprehension. Instead, use a normal for loop and `break` once you find a match: then you're guaranteed there'll only be one match (if you want to go beyond that, you can use the for-else idiom if there is no match, but that's a not so commonly used idiom).

Comment: List comprehensions are incredibly useful, but I don't think you've explained your problem well enough to know if it's appropriate for your case.

Comment: What should happen in the case where there is more than one match?

Comment: @9769953 blanket advice can be harmful.  Sometimes you just want to wrap a non-critical operation so that things will continue to work regardless of the error.

Comment: Thank you for everyone comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's indeed only one match, don't use a list comprehension. Instead, use a normal for loop and break once you find a match: then you're guaranteed there'll only be one match:

```
# I want to find COM port by using specific hwid  
regex_vplogVID = re.compile(r'{\S+}_VID')  
port_device = None
for port in listport.comports():
    if re.findall(regex_vplogVID, port.hwid):
       port_device = port.device
       break
```

---

Bonus: if you want to go beyond that, you can use the for-else idiom if there is no match, but that's a not so commonly used idiom, and often confuses people:

```
# I want to find COM port by using specific hwid 
regex_vplogVID = re.compile(r'{\S+}_VID')   
for port in listport.comports():
    if re.findall(regex_vplogVID, port.hwid):
       port_device = port.device
       break
else:  # no break encountered
    raise ValueError("COM port not found")
# No need now to have a default of `None` and check for it
vplogserial = ser.Serial(port_device[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `for` loop, if only because you can stop iterating early once you find the unique device.

```
for n in listport.comports():
    if re.findall(regex_vplogVID, n.hwid):
        vplogserial = ser.Serial(n.device)
        break
```

Comment: or a generator wrapped in a `next(gen, None)`